# Hibernate 5.4.10.Final. Fail-safe cleanup (collections). Infinity loop or smth like it

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, stack-overflow

I have news and tags that has many to many relation. When i like to get all news or tags i get StackOverflowError. I added screen of log file, there is something like infinity loop and big number of the same message. There is some problem of parsing result from db. Each method that returns entity leads to the same problem.

When i switch FetchType.EAGER to Lazy there is no problem. But i like to get entities with all fields after query.

What is the problem?

Mapping, query creating and log file attached.
Thanks

mapping in news:

[image]

mapping in tags:

[image]

log file:

[image]

find method:

[image]

create query:

[image]

Comment: Could you show `equals` and `hashCode` methods of your entities?

Comment: @amseager Oh man. thank you. I forgot to change these methods and they referred to each other. After fix everything works. Thanks!